# Google’s AMP batchGet API only accepts a server key; how do I use it from an Android app?

Tags: android, google-api, amp-html

Google’s [AMP Cache URL API](https://developers.google.com/amp/cache/reference/acceleratedmobilepageurl/rest/v1/ampUrls/batchGet) is a way to discover if there’s an AMP version of any given URL. But it only accepts [server keys](https://developers.google.com/amp/cache/reference/authorizing) for authorization. This presents two problems:

1. Server keys should not be embedded into client apps to prevent quota theft; Android clients should use keys that are signed with the app’s signing key.
2. Google limits quota on a per-key basis*, so sharing this limited quota among multiple app users is not feasible.

How do I access this Google API from a client app?

* Can someone confirm if this assumption is correct?

Comment: Have you checked if using [HTTP request](https://developers.google.com/amp/cache/reference/acceleratedmobilepageurl/rest/v1/ampUrls/batchGet),  ampUrls.batchGet, works in Android?

Comment: Yes, I have it fully implemented using server keys. With no key, the HTTP API returns an authorization error. I’m not using any client libraries; just making the raw HTTP calls.

Comment: did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

The general thinking is that finding out if a link has an AMP equivalent is something you should do on your server rather than in your client app. This lets you cache the result which reduces the load on Google's servers. Your app then calls you server and gets the content that way.